# Python parallelisation of encapsulated for cycle with numba prange. Why not working

Tags: python, numba

In doing some experiments to parallelise 3 encapsulated for cycle with numba, I realised that a naive approach is actually not improving the performance. 
The following code produce the following times (in seconds):

```
0.154625177383  # no numba
0.420143127441  # numba first time (lazy initialisation)
0.196285963058  # numba second time
0.200047016144  # nubma third time
0.199403047562  # nubma fourth time
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange
import time


def run_1():
    dims = [100,100,100]
    a = np.zeros(dims)
    for x in range(100):
        for y in range(100):
            for z in range(100):
                a[x,y,z] = 1
    return a

@jit
def run_2():
    dims = [100,100,100]
    a = np.zeros(dims)
    for x in prange(100):
        for y in prange(100):
            for z in prange(100):
                a[x,y,z] = 1
    return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    run_1()
    elapsed1 = time.time() - t
    print elapsed1

    t = time.time()
    run_2()
    elapsed2 = time.time() - t
    print elapsed2

    t = time.time()
    run_2()
    elapsed3 = time.time() - t
    print elapsed3

    t = time.time()
    run_2()
    elapsed3 = time.time() - t
    print elapsed3

    t = time.time()
    run_2()
    elapsed3 = time.time() - t
    print elapsed3
```

Comment: 1) Your testcode is completely memory bound. The CPU has almost nothing to do here. 2) In a more sophisticated example parallelize only the outer loop. Overparallization has a bad cache behaivour and comes with some overhead.

Comment: @max911 thanks for the comment. I tried to use prange only for the first loop with the same result. Probably I am missing the basics on parallelisation...

Comment: As @9000 said, your example is far to simple. Use an abitrary but complex formula to calculate a[x,y,z] eg a[x,y,z]=np.sin(x)**3+ np.cos(y)**15+ np.sqrt(x*15 + y*12+z*20+np.log(15+x) and you would see a difference. There is simpy nothing to calculate in your example....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if there's any code to JIT in these loops: there's no non-trivial *Python* code to compile, only thin wrappers over C code (yes, `range` is C code). Possibly the JIT only adds overhead trying to profile and generate (unsuccessfully) more efficient code.

If you want speed-up, think about [parallelization using scipy](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/ParallelProgramming) or maybe [direct access to NumPy arrays from Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html).